# Error when trying to view revisions

Tags: 8, nodes

Using Drupal 8/9. When trying to view previous revisions I am getting the following error:

```
Error: Call to a member function getType() on string in clc_d8_theme_theme_suggestions_page_alter() (line 13 of /var/www/html/wrc/web/themes/clc_d8_theme/clc_d8_theme.theme)
```

It refers to this code:

```php
function clc_d8_theme_theme_suggestions_page_alter(array &$suggestions, array $variables) {
  // Add content type suggestions.
  if ($node = \Drupal::request()->attributes->get('node')) {
    array_splice($suggestions, 1, 0, 'page__node__' . $node->getType()); <-- error at this line
  }
}
```

I need the type suggestions for my theme. How do I fix this? I thought the check on the node would be enough to avoid issues.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"`$node`" can vary a bit by context, but here are some ways to set `$node`:

```
$routeName = \Drupal::routeMatch()->getRouteName();

$node = NULL;

// $variables['node'].
if (isset($variables['node'])) {
  $node = $variables['node'];
  if (is_numeric($variables['node'])) {
    $node = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('node')->load($variables['node']);
  }
}

// $variables['row'].
if (isset($variables['row']) && !empty($variables['row']->nid)) {
  $node = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('node')->load($variables['row']->nid);
}

// $routeName === 'entity.node.canonical'.
if ($routeName === 'entity.node.canonical') {
  $node = \Drupal::routeMatch()->getParameter('node');
}

// $routeName === 'entity.node.revision'.
if ($routeName === 'entity.node.revision') {
  $revisionId = \Drupal::routeMatch()->getParameter('node_revision')->getRevisionId();
  $node = node_revision_load($revisionId);
}

// $routeName === 'entity.node.preview'.
if ($routeName === 'entity.node.preview') {
  $node = \Drupal::routeMatch()->getParameter('node_preview');
}

if ($node) {
  // run your code...
}
```

Specifically, it looks like you're after:

```
// Get route name.
$routeName = \Drupal::routeMatch()->getRouteName();

// Check if route is node revision.
if ($routeName === 'entity.node.revision') {
  $revisionId = \Drupal::routeMatch()->getParameter('node_revision')->getRevisionId();
  $node = node_revision_load($revisionId);
}
```

This will fully load your node object and `->getType()` should work without error.